# Embedding local video using Django

Tags: django, video, web

I'm using Django to create a webpage which displays a videoclip which will be created by the visitor her/himself. The following is my code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django import forms
import numpy as np
from math import e
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper

class NumForm(forms.Form):
    n1 = forms.FloatField(label = 'Slope_Upper')
    n2 = forms.FloatField(label = 'Slope_Lower')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-3, 3), ylim=(0, 1))
ax.grid()
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

def psych(x,y,z):
    return 1/(1+e**(-1*y*(x-z)))

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def animate(i, lo, up):

    x = np.linspace(-3,3,1000)
    dif = up - lo
    y = psych(x,.001*(up-lo)*i,0)
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,


def graph(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NumForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            sl_u = form.cleaned_data['n1']
            sl_l = form.cleaned_data['n2']
            anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                           fargs=(sl_l, sl_u), frames=300, interval=20, blit=True)
            anim.save(filename='video.mp4', fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
            return render(request, 'plotting/video2.html')
    else:
        form = NumForm()

    return render(request, 'plotting/retry.html', {'form': form})
```

And 'video2.html' is like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <embed src="file:///c:/plot/video.mp4">
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run the local server and visit the webpage, I simply can't play the video. (The play button is not activated.) The question is: How could I play the video 'video.mp4', which is in my local folder, on the webpage I've created using Django?

Comment: Rule of thumb - relative URLs only - no absolute urls. Make sure the mp4 is inside the project, and use relative paths to load the file. Also, please use `video` tag instead of `embed`

Comment: It does not work regardless of whether I use the absolute or relative path...

Comment: ok try to serve as media file like `{{MEDIA_URL}}/plot/video.mp4`

Comment: There is nothing dynamic about your video embedding, so no need to tag or show your Django code for this. And you might want to consider using html5 for this. I suggest you do some proper research on how to embed videos first.

Answer (score 0):

The "controls" attribute adds video controls, like play, pause, and volume.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="{{MEDIA_URL}}/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```